# sort a list of tuple containing string

Tags: python, string, list, sorting, tuples

I have a list of tuples like this:

```
data = [('ab15', 'abc'), ('ab4', 'abc'), ('ab12', 'abc'), ('ab7', 'abc')]
```

An I want to sort by the first element of the subset, to have:

```
[('ab4', 'abc'), ('ab7', 'abc'), ('ab10', 'abc'), ('ab12', 'abc')]
```

I tried to use sorted:    `sorted(data)` But with this,  I have:

```
[('ab10', 'abc'), ('ab12', 'abc'), ('ab4', 'abc'), ('ab7', 'abc')]
```

What is not what I wan't. Is there an easy way to do it ?

Thanks

Comment: print sorted(data,key=lambda x: int(x[0][2:]))

Comment: @Moj: Yes `ab` part is fixed
@sundarnatarajСундар: Thanks for your answer, it works !